# running telnet.exe inside windows container simply exists

Tags: docker

I created an image with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-windowsservercore-ltsc2019 AS base
USER ContainerAdministrator
RUN powershell.exe -Command Add-WindowsFeature "telnet-client"
```

I started the container via command: `docker run -it --network=nat <image>`

Inside the container I executed the following command: `telnet <myhost>`

I get back the command prompt without any error messages, without `%errorlevel%` setting.

Pinging from the same command prompt works flawlessly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try this instead of the PowerShell command: `dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:TelnetClient`.

Comment: General FYI: if the host you're trying to `telnet` into supports SSH, use SSH instead, as `telnet` has no encryption and sends all data as plaintext, including passwords. `telnet` should always be avoided unless the firmware is so old, it doesn't support SSH

Comment: @harrymc same result.

Comment: @JW0914 I do not want to use telnet as a remote access tool. I want it to use as a network access check tool. Like we test SMTP or HTTP server via telneting on its service port and typing commands manually.

Comment: Try to run Docker with `--network=host`. ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68317324/tcp-telnet-from-inside-docker-container))

Comment: @harrymc Thx, but: ````docker: Error response from daemon: network host not found.```` It's a windows container on a windows host.

Comment: Seems like the `host` network was not created. Use `docker info` to see the names of the created networks and try them out. The right one might be `transparent`, but I can't test it myself.

Comment: The solution became: I built a POC telnet.exe in .net and added it to the image above. It is working flawlessly without any other settings.